# Reversed freezing point

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, phase-transition

[Helium-3's Phase diagram](http://ltl.tkk.fi/research/theory/helium.html) shows that at the right temperature and pressure combination, the solid region dips *downward* as temperature increases. That means that you can *heat it up and it will freeze*. What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazingly, below 0.3K the latent heat of fusion of $^3$He is negative i.e. you need to inject heat to make the solid freeze. This is the basis of [Pomeranchuk cooling](http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/PomeranchukCooling.html).

This is miles outside my area of expertise, but I believe it's because in the liquid you get large scale alignment of the spins called para magnons, and these lower the energy of the liquid relative to the solid.

Comment: "large scale alignment of the spins called para magnons" so they lower energy and entropy so much that the solid actually is more disordered and in a higher energy state. Strange.

Comment: When it freezes you also do work. SO the He is sucking up both heat and work!